# Python auto-login webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to auto-login to a webpage using the following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def page_is_loaded(driver):
 return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get("http://blabla.htm")
 wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 wait.until(page_is_loaded)
 email_field = driver.find_element_by_id("sap-user")
 email_field.send_keys("foo")
 password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("sap-password")
 password_field.send_keys("blabla")
 password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The code is working fine. In the next step I want to open the firefox window after login is done. Can you please help?
I was trying with :

```
 driver.open()
```

Comment: When you run: driver = webdriver.Firefox(). You should already see Firefox open with a new window. Is this not the case?

Comment: No firefox window opens.

Comment: Ok I have resolved it. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was being caused due to wrong indentation. The following code has the desired result:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://blabla.htm")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)
email_field = driver.find_element_by_id("sap-user")
email_field.send_keys("foo")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("sap-password")
password_field.send_keys("blabla")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
page_is_loaded()
```

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I've heard of Python bugs caused by wrong tabbing, I'd buy Python and erase it from the earth.